# Avoid Adding Custom Headers for every request in WCF?

Tags: wcf

I had a wcf service, provided by one of our team which need to be authenticated every time from SoapHeader as

```
scope = new OperationContextScope(objVendorServiceClient.InnerChannel);
header= MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Token", "NameSpace", Session["Token"]);
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);
```

AFAIK, as HTTP is Stateless Protocol, i need to add these lines everytime for every request. But as per the requirement, i should not call these (either in a function or directly) for every request explicitly in my code. So what i am planning to do is, by adding HTTPHANDLER, before sending Request can we add these custom headers to actual request through HTTP?. If yes could any one give me a suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally with the help  of Leo Tang, i achieved this. He suggested me to use Message Inspectors which worked as a champ. Please find the link for further reference

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/4da32c89-b839-49af-805a-69e85bffecd8